# what is "Update Model on All Projects" in visual studio solution context?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework

When I right-click on my solution in visual studio, one of the things in the opened context I can click on is *Update Model on All Projects*. 
Below image shows what I'm talking about:
[image]

My visual studio version is `15.9.5`
By the way I've added an EF  model to one of the projects in my solution. But it is not seen in *Pending Changes* section . I don't know if it has anything to do with the question or not.

Comment: 1: make a backup (commit)  2: try it.

Comment: I would guess it loops through all of your models and updates them, the same as if you open the model manually and right click and press update.

Comment: @NibblyPig I right-clicked on the file which was not present in *Pending Changes*, there was an option *Add to Source Control*. Seems the file was not included in source control automatically(I don't know why).After that the *Update Model On All Projects* disappeared.

Comment: Seems no one in the world knows what that thing really is and does! 
Seems it is documented no where!